# How can I detect view overflow in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I am wanting to implement a custom text wrap strategy for my application running 0.59.9. There are portions of the app where time ranges are used (ex. '9/12/2019 8:00 AM - 10:00 AM EST') and especially on smaller devices or users with larger font scaling none of the baked in textWrap / numberOfLines options can handle quite what I want.

I would like it to break at a specified location, specifically the '-' in the timestamp. Is there a way to do this? Maybe a listener exists for isViewOverflowed that a developer can hook into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to break apart the string into two parts and just have a `Text` container which flows inline if there's enough space. Otherwise it will overflow.

```html
<Text>
  <Text>9/12/2019 8:00 AM</Text>
  <Text>10:00 AM EST</Text>
</Text>
```